# Can't click on an element that is overlapped by another element using (sypress framework)

Tags: cypress

I want to click on the element

```
        cy.visit('https://test.com:1111/')        
        cy.get('button').click()
        cy.contains('Configuration').click()
        cy.get('ant-tabs-tab').contains('Blocks').click()
```

but this element is overlapped by another element with CypressError:

```
Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element:
  <div role="tab" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" class=" ant-tabs-tab"> Blocks </div>
is being covered by another element:
  <ul class="ant-menu menu ant-menu-dark ant-menu-root ant-menu-horizontal" role="menu" style="line-height: 64px;">...</ul>
Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{force: true}` with `click()` to disable error checks:

```
cy.visit('https://test.com:1111/')
cy.get('button').click({force: true})
cy.contains('Configuration').click({force: true})
cy.get('ant-tabs-tab').contains('Blocks').click({force: true})
```